# Does the new Dragon Ball Super opening proves that Gohan is going to recover his mystic form?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the new Dragon Ball Super opening (you can see it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FN57gmQlmLU)

it's seen Gohan raising his ki in base form and sparking electricity. Is this proof that he recovered his mystic form or can a saiyan or any other race (human, namekian, etc) spark electricity when raising his ki in base form?

Comment: The sparks are nothing but ki (check DBWikia for *Ki*). So theoretically anyone can achieve it by having an excess of ki. Proof for mystic form? Nothing can be said for now. It's just wait and watch.

Comment: why you dont post your comment as answer?

Comment: The opening is just a sneak peak for the arc, we don't really know what is what. But there is always a twist in every arc.

Comment: @Pablo I thought the same thing that Ero Sennin-senpai thought. But honestly I think it's best to wait until the Universal tournament arc drops. If Gohan fights in it we should be able to tell. But given that Gohan became a super saiyan twice in the filler right now I'd assume no. But I don't think there is enough proof yet to provide a credible answer to your question.

Comment: @Pablo Thanks for the offer. But I prefer to post answers that contain full explanations using factual evidence. I might post when it has been disclosed in the series :)

Comment: btw, talking about predictions, this guy predicted the super saiyan blue kaioken a year ealier. That was an amazing prediction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSMY3mAea3U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in episode 88 of Dragon Ball Super he recovers his mystic form, and now is clear the opening was meant to show that. (spoilers behind)

> By training with Piccolo, Gohan first recovers his SSJ2 form which we havent seen him using it since the early Buu Saga in Dragon Ball Z. Piccolo is a match for him in SSJ and later in SSJ2, (Piccolo is even stronger than Gohan SSJ2) and later Gohan recovers his mystic form and gets stronger than Piccolo who ends with one of his arm cut by 2 by Gohan

Answer (score 2):

I think it indeed is a form that he is coming up with. It may not be a proof of he getting back to his Mystique form, however it sure looks similar to what happened before Goku and Vegeta went Blue for the first time.

I have personally watched that part of the opening quite a few times. Mystique or now, but it sure is a new form.